# How to create a new tabs section on product detail page and add tabs as required?

Tags: frontend, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to add custom tabs in a new section on product detail page and not the existing "detailed_info" group where generally tabs are being added.

You can see the screenshot as given below :

[image]

Let me know, if its possible and how ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To extend default tabs on `PDP` use this structure

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="my.tab" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Information</argument>
                    </arguments>
     </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

To create new tab group i think you need:

1. Copy `module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml` template
2. Set different name for file and modify line

   ```
   $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') to $block->getGroupChildNames('my_tab_group', 'getChildHtml')
   ```

3 add this layout to catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="my.new.tabs" template="product/view/new_details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="my_tab_group">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </block>
```